# Is there any good Xamarin form control for Hijri / Gregorian calendar?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am looking for a good and reliable control which can provide Hijri / Gregorian in Xamarin forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any free Calendar component which can serve Gregorian and Hijri both.

Well, here I created one for my project use. See if it helps
Git: https://github.com/afzalali15/MECalendar
NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MECalendar/

**It has Greg, Hijri and Greg with Arabic text.**